# How to add drop caps in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, cs5

It's an option in InDesign, CSS, and MS Word. I'm not finding it in Photoshop CS5.

Answer (score 6):

Photoshop has no automated drop cap feature. You will have to create two separate text elements and "fake" the drop cap.

In reality, Photoshop is not designed to be a type-intensive application. If it were, it would at least have a glyphs panel.

Comment: I take minor issue with "fake drop cap": in PS, you are manually creating something which has been automated in the other programs. The easiest way (the 2 element way mention by scott) is to create the body text sans the first Letter, with a first line indent large enough for the size of the desired dropped cap. Limit yourself to a size which only forces a runaround of one line.

Comment: "Fake" was placed in quotes because one would be creating manually what other apps do automatically. I realize the drop cap technique has been around long before even Gutenberg. :)